# Need to identify and replace a piece of a string in line

Tags: sql, regex, netezza

I'm working on a netezza database with the extension toolkit installed. I'm relatively new to the work, and I've got an issue with a script I'm supposed to be created.

My task is to be able to identify if a specific numeric value is included in a column, and if it is, replace it in line.

For example, if the value is "This string contains this restricted value 4402631524852147 and it needs masked", my script needs to make those changes to be "This string contains this restricted value ************2147 and it needs masked"

I've been able to create a query using sqlext..regexpextract and sqleext..regexp_like to identify the values, but I can't figure out how to replace the strings in line.

Query I've used to identify the values:

```
    SELECT ${COLUMN_NAME},'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'||SUBSTR(${COLUMN_NAME},13,4) as 
MASKED_ID
FROM ${TABLE_NAME} 
WHERE sqlext..regexp_like(${COLUMN_NAME},'[0-9]{16}','I')
AND SUBSTR(sqlext..regexp_extract(${COLUMN_NAME},'[0-9]{16}','I'),1,6) in
('440263')
```

Is there a way to use perhaps sqlext..regexp_replace? Or another SQL command to replace in line?

Comment: You can't do that easily with PostgreSQL regexp. If you had access to an ICU regex engine (MySQL 8.x+), you could use [this](https://regex101.com/r/b75adM/1).

Comment: Unfortunately I think I'm stuck with using Netezza PostgreSQL regexp options. I appreciate the response though, and I'll definitely keep this in mind if the requirements change.

Comment: Netezza has nothing to do with Postgres (except that both were designed by the same person)

Comment: Understood, just usually mention Postgres because Netezza isn't as prevalent and the syntax is similar. I am using Netezza.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use regex_replace for that purpose: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.1.0/com.ibm.nz.sqltk.doc/r_sqlext_regexp_replace.html